# HTTP status Unauthorized

Tags: azure, botframework

I have problem with deployment, I have created functional bot that perfectly works till I don't insert Microsoft App Id & Microsoft App Password to my appsettings.json file. When I deploying Bot to Azure portal and trying to test Web Chat, I got a problem : HTTP status code Unauthorized. App Id and Password I got from created resource Bot Channel Registration , any suggestions what I'am doing not right? I'll be Thankfully for any answers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have both a Web App Bot resource and Bot Channels Registration resource? Bot Channels Registration is for bots you are hosting elsewhere and you're essentially just providing an endpoint. You should be using the app id and password from your Web App Bot resource.

Comment: Thank you for the answering, I will try, and inform or it success.